# падскажите пожалуста не появлятся кнопка вверх

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На консоле паказывает ошибку  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```js
$(function(){
    //Knopka
    $('body').append('<button clas="btn_up1"/>');

});
```

```css
.btn_up1{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    background:#333;
    z-index: 100; 
}

.btn_up1:after{
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    top:4px; bottom: 0;
    left:0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'button clas='     еще одну букву s пропустили

Comment: Пменял не работает на консоле пишет  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: а jQuery подключен?

Comment: нет а без него ни как

Comment: вы же используете его синтаксис. На голом js это все делается не так

Comment: вот так на js https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document

Comment: А тепер мне что делать

Comment: добавить jQuery в проект  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить где-то вверху страницы вот это:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Чтобы jQuery работал. Хотя сейчас зачастую отказываются от jQ, потому что все его фишки можно легко повторить на чистом JS. В вашем случае:

```
(function(){
    let elem = document.createElement('button');
    elem.className = "btn_up1";
    elem.innerText = "Вверх";
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
})();
```

Или:

```
(function(){
    document.body.innerHTML += '<button class="btn_up1">Вверх</button>';
})();
```

(первый вариант вроде как работает быстрее, но для одной кнопки не существенно)

А на jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').append('<button class="btn_up1">Вверх</button>');
});
```

---

Но я всё равно не понял, в чем проблема прямо в HTML написать эту кнопку и через CSS прикрутить его к концу страницы:

```
<style> .btn_up1 {position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10%}</style>
<button class="btn_up1">Вверх</button>
```

Обычно к скриптам прибегают, если пользователь в процессе должен что-то добавлять или убирать по клику. А у вас кнопка и так сразу загружается. Никому не нравится по 15 секунд ждать загрузки, потому что на сайте всё сделано на скриптах... CSS всегда быстрее.